# Two fivetran connectors, one shopify store

Tags: shopify, fivetran

I am attempting to connect a fivetran connector to a shopify store, and they allow another 3rd party to connect to the same shopify store also using fivetran.

If I proceed is this likely to cause any issues

Nothing as of yet as I don't want to break anything :D